# Empty/Corrupted Content Assist with pydev 5.5.0, eclipse Neon.2 on RHEL 7

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I've been using Eclipse + PyDev for a number of years now.  A few months back, content assist stopped fully working and here's an example screenshot of what I see:
[image: example pydev screenshot]

So the suggestions do not appear, the title does not appear on the documentation pane, but the documentation does appear?  In general, I have seen issues as my Gnome environment uses 'focus follows mouse' and that causes some UI pain in eclipse, but am unsure what is to blame for this.

I am using Eclipse for PHP Developers, Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2), Build id: 20161208-0600 on Oracle 1.8.0_121 64bit JVM, Redhat Linux 7 64bit, Gnome desktop, "focus follows mouse".  I do start eclipse with `SW_GTK3=1`

Comment: Have you tried starting with SWT_GTK3=0 ? Do you know if this happens with other plugins (say a code-completion with JDT -- Java Tools)?

Comment: Thank you.  I tried starting with `SWT_GTK3=0` and that did not help.  It appears JDT -- Java Tools is showing no results for code completion, but I have to <cntrl>-space to manually invoke it.

Comment: Eh, I moved my `~/.p2` `~/.eclipse` `~/eclipse` and `~/workspace` folders out of the way and started over from scratch.  code assist works again :( This is a goose chase :(